# Пользовательский скроллбар на jQuery.

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Вот хотел сделать слайдер из квадратных блоков по 5 фото на развороте
и стрелочки. Когда нажимаешь на стрелочки картинки смещаются на одну вправо или влево в зависимости от нажатой стрелки. У кого есть исходник готовый, ну или ссылка, где можно скачать исходник, скиньте, пожалуйста.
Cкинуть можно сюда:
@mail - murad_2008.88@mail.ru
Skype - murad886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть, [отсюда](http://cake-php-blog.net/25-jquery-sliders) что-то подойдет.

Comment: Кто знает где можно скачать типа такой галереи <br>
http://www.ivi.ru/<br>
Внизу показано, 5 картинок на обороте и стрелочка вправо влево.<br>
5 картинок на обороте <br>
Спасибо заранее, весьма буду благодарен.<br>

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://www.enova-tech.net/files/jMyCarousel/examples/example1.html), как вариант. На 5 штук я думаю допилите.

Comment: А ссылочки нет чтобы можно было скачать

Comment: Хотя все скачал. спасибо большое за ссылку